# KML polygon rainbow filled colors is showing only as simple color?

Tags: kml, contour, color, qgis-2.18

I draw filled color contour in Surfer application
[image]

I imported this file to Google Earth as .kml file 
[image]

There is no problem so far
I tried to import the same file to QGIS 2.18.28 
But the colors is not showing correctly 
There is only one simple color 
[image]

How can I fix it ?

Comment: `Right-click the layer -> Properties -> Style -> Change Single Symbol to graduated color`, and select the field that represents the values that you want to show their color. Then select the color ramp that you want. Finally click on Classify.

Answer (score 1):

`Properties` of the layer (either by RMB or double-click), choose the `style`-tab, change to `classified`, run the classification based on the column containing your values, choose a fitting colorramp.

Also, QGIS does only know how to style new layers if a `.qml`-file with the same name as that layer is saved at the same place.